# Upload images to instagram using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to do a simple Instagram python bot in order to upload images in my Instagram profile. I've already tried the most common libraries (InstagramAPI, instapy, insta-cly). While I was searching I found out that Instagram has changed something making those libraries useless.

Is there any library I can use? I know thatI can use Selenium in order to make it go but I'm wondering if there is any shortcut.

Trank you!

Comment: I was trying this with instapy-cli myself right now, and it seems like it is a little buggy.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I can log in but not upload pictures. I've read people in forums with the same problems. If it works for you, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: No luck on my end either. From testing it, it appears that it's a bad http request (400 error), but I would guess that it wouldn't be so popular had it never worked. Maybe Instagram changed one of the endpoints. I think the fastest route would probably be to resolve that issue and to fix the http request (but I wouldn't say it's that fast). This is definitely a useful question.

Comment: Isn't Instagram about to deprecate their API? I think most of those Python libraries are broken at the moment.

Comment: @gilbertohasnofb interesting - didn't know that. It says that they aren't actively maintained, but didn't know it was that bad. Is there a reason why they don't maintain them?

Comment: So I used to use a Python package named `InstagramAPI`, and there were a lot of discussions about it in the repo. Unfortunately, the author has recently deleted instead of archived the repository. About their API, they are going to replace the old one (known as Legacy API) with a new one, but apparently the new one is far more restrictive and will require all 3rd party apps and plugins to apply for permission to use it, according to [this source](https://embedsocial.com/blog/instagram-api-changes-2020/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this library: instabot https://pypi.org/project/instabot/

example of code for uploading an image:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="instagram_username", password="your_password")

file = open('path_to_your_image', 'r')
bot.upload_photo(file, caption="your post caption")
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked perfect and few minutes ago I uploaded my first picture. By the way: Did you know if there are some parameter or way of uploading a vertical image instead of a horizontal photo? Thanks!!

Comment: Dont know if its a package update, but the bot.upload_photo should receive the path to the media item, and not a file instance

Comment: I'm triyng this approach, but the script seems to be blocked by Instagram. It returns error 400 and my image isn't being uploaded. Is somebody having this issue ?

Comment: is there a way to upload videos ?

Comment: Does InstaBot still work? I know Instagram got rid of a ton of dev features. I've been testing it out and getting really weird errors. I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: Hey George. I use instabot on a daily basis to upload photos :)

Comment: I tried something like this recently and it worked the first few times, but then it seemed like Instagram somehow caught on and I started getting <Response [400]> errors.

Comment: @PastExpiry.com I have found the same issue lately with one of my scripts, it looks like this solution isn't available anymore

Answer (score 3):

Instabot python library allows you to upload images, stories, videos, make comments and much much more, but there are problems that are not resolved in other answers, so I wrote this code that takes care about all of that for you.

```
from instabot import Bot
import os
import shutil


def clean_up():
    dir = "config"
    remove_me = "imgs\img.jpg.REMOVE_ME"
    # checking whether config folder exists or not
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        try:
            # removing it because in 2021 it makes problems with new uploads
            shutil.rmtree(dir)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
    if os.path.exists(remove_me):
        src = os.path.realpath("imgs\img.jpg")
        os.rename(remove_me, src)


def upload_post():
    bot = Bot()

    bot.login(username="your_username", password="your_password")
    bot.upload_photo("imgs/img.jpg", caption="Caption for the post")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_up()
    upload_post()
```

Comment: it is necessary to change the path "imgs/img.jpg" to folder where you store images that you want to upload.