# Upload vertical images to instagram using Python

Tags: python, instagram

I'm taking the risk to be marked as duplicated with [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293200/upload-images-to-instagram-using-python) I wanted to know if there's a way to upload vertical images using the instabot library. So far I used the following code to upload images to an IG account:

```
from instabot import Bot 

username = "dosisdelpasado"
password = "**************"
image_path = "path/path"
caption = "aun sigo testeando"

bot = Bot() 
bot.login(username=username, password=password) 

result = bot.upload_photo(image_path,caption= caption)
```

The main issue is that `instabot` doesn't distinguish between vertical-oriented and horizontal-oriented images, and assume that all of them are vertical images. Digging a little bit in the source code, I came to this function defined inside `api_phot.py`, which seems to identify the pixel size of the image, as `get_image_size(fname)` and `compatible_aspect_ratio(size)`, but after a while of playing with the code, I didn't solve this annoying problem.

Will be really useful if you can help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: do you have the same problem when you try to upload this image directly on instagram ? Maybe file keeps data as horizontal image with flag which inform program to display it as  vertical - and most image viewers may respect this flag but maybe instagram doesn't respect it.

Comment: Oh no, with the regular procedure IG behaves well. Somehow the app understands the orientation of a particular image. But I'm very lazy about uploading images, and I have thousands of those so I want to automatize this process, but only work whit horizontal-oriented images.

Comment: I ask for this to recognize if this problem is only in `instabot` or `instagram`. I thing I would have to test `instabot` with different image - real horizontal, vertical with flag horizontal - to see if this is really problem with this flag. If this is problem with flag then it would need code which convert image from `vertical with flag horizontal` to `real vertical` before sending.

Comment: @NicolásMedina I see that `instabot` works with aspect ratios in the range 4:5 (~0.8) (square-ish portrait) to 90:47 (~1.9) (almost 2:1 landscape). You can check this range in `compatible_aspect_ratio()`. If the image is narrower (more portrait-y) or wider (more landscape-y) than this defined range, then the library will either force resize it or not upload the photo. What you could do is _change the minimum value of this range_ of aspect-ratios defined in `compatible_aspect_ratio()`, such that it includes the aspect ratio of your vertical image (Ex:- portrait with aspect ratio < 0.5).

Comment: @skuzzy Thanks for the advice, I tried to modify the parameters that contain the dimensional's ratio of pictures, but it didn't work properly, given that the photo was uploaded horizontally in all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the "instabot" library, try using "instapy_cli". Here is what the code would look like:

```py
from instapy_cli import client

username = "dosisdelpasado"
password = "**************"
image_path = "path/path"
caption = "aun sigo testeando"
 
with client(username, password) as bot:
    bot.upload(image_path, caption)
```

Comment: mmm well, I tried to use the library but did not work as expected. It is written in python2.7? I'm currently using python 3. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: This library is written for python3. I am not sure why it isn't working for you. Are you getting an error message? Try pip installing `pynstagram` and rerun it.